Implicit function theorem and sensitivities to market risk for Nelson-Siegel-Svensson model
I’m calibrating the Nelson-Siegel-Svensson model to market rates and I’m trying to compute the sensitivities of the NSS parameters to those said rates:
$$r\left(T\right)=\beta_{0}+\beta_{1}{\frac{\left[{1-\exp\left({-T/\lambda}\right)}\right]}{T/\lambda}}+\beta_{2}{\left({\frac{\left[{1-\exp\left({-T/\lambda}\right)}\right]}{T/\lambda}}-\exp\left({-T/\lambda}\right)\right)}+\beta_{3}{\left({\frac{\left[{1-\exp\left({-T/\kappa}\right)}\right]}{T/\kappa}}-\exp\left({-T/\kappa}\right)\right)}.$$
I'm calibrating the model using Levenberg-Marquardt algorithm.
Let's call the parameters $b=\{\beta_0^*,\beta_1^*,\beta_2^*,\beta_3^*,\lambda^*,\kappa^*\}\in\mathbb{R}^{n=6}$, such that, for $m$ observed rates in the market for $m$ maturities ($m>n$), we have:
$$\forall i = 1,...,m, \, f_{i}(r_{i},T_{i};b)=r(T_i;b) - r_i=0.$$
What I want to compute is the sensitivities of $b$ w.r.t ${r_1,...,r_m}$:
$$\frac{\partial b}{\partial r}={\begin{pmatrix}{\dfrac {\partial \beta_0^*}{\partial r_{1}}}&\cdots &{\dfrac {\partial \beta_0^*}{\partial r_{m}}}\\\vdots &\ddots &\vdots \\{\dfrac {\partial \kappa^*}{\partial r_{1}}}&\cdots &{\dfrac {\partial \kappa^*}{\partial r_{m}}}\end{pmatrix}}\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times m}.$$
I found this paper which is the closest to possibly have the answer to my problem:

From model to market risks: The Implicit Function Theorem (IFT) demystified

But I'm still missing some things. It says the following (page. 3): using the implicit function theorem, we have
$$\underbrace{\frac{\partial b}{\partial r}}_{n\times m}=\underbrace{\left(\frac{\partial I}{\partial b}\right)^{-1}}_{m\times i}\left[\underbrace{\frac{\partial I}{\partial r}}_{i\times n}-\underbrace{\frac{\partial I}{\partial c}}_{i\times p}\underbrace{\frac{\partial c}{\partial r}}_{p\times n}\right]$$
with:

$I$ being a "set of $i$ calibrated instruments" (?)
$c$ being a "set of $p$ additional parameters" (?)

That's where I fail to go further. In my specific case, what are my set $I$ and $c$?

To my understanding, there exist two ways to invoke the IFT in quantitative finance applications in a calibration / bootstrapping context.

When minimizing some error function during bootstrapping.
When bootstrapping a set of parameters (e.g. a zero curve) so that all reference instruments are priced exactly to par (e.g. zero PV for a swap),

IFT in optimization problems
I understand that you tackle the first question, where you minimize a scalar error function. To simplify notation, collect all the parameters into the $K \times 1$ vector $\theta$ and write
$$
\min_{\theta} f(\theta,y) = \sum_i\left(y(T_i)-r(T_i,\theta)\right)^2
$$
Once the minimization of $f$ has been performed, we have obtained some optimal $\theta^*$. From optimization theory, we know that the following optimization condition must hold at the optimum:
$$
g\equiv\left.\frac{\mathrm{d}f(\theta,y)}{\mathrm{d}\theta}\right|_{\theta=\theta^*}=0
$$
This can be used as the starting point for finding the relationship between changes in input data and the calibrated parameters. In layman's terms: When the inputs $y$ change (by a little bit), the optimization routine will still induce that $g=0$ at the optimum, i.e. it stays at zero:
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm{d}g}{\mathrm{d}y}&=
\frac{\mathrm{d}g}{\mathrm{d}\theta}\frac{\mathrm{d}\theta}{\mathrm{d}y}+\frac{\mathrm{d}g}{\mathrm{d}y}=0 \\
\Rightarrow \frac{\mathrm{d}\theta}{\mathrm{d}y}&=-\left(\frac{\mathrm{d}g}{\mathrm{d}\theta}\right)^{-1}\frac{\mathrm{d}g}{\mathrm{d}y}
\end{align}
$$
Hence, given our scalar optimization problem $f$, the relationship between (small) changes to the inputs and the calibrated parameters are found using derivatives of the first-order-condition.
Let's try this for the NSS example you provide, assuming we want to minimize the squared errors. Further, let us introduce simplifying notation:

$g_i$ is the the $k\times 1$ gradient of the NSS model at $T_i$, and
$H_i$ is the $k\times k$ matrix of second derivatives of the NSS model at $T_i$.

Then:
$$
\begin{align}
f&=\sum_i(y_i-r(T_i))^2\\
g&\equiv \frac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}\theta}=-2\sum_i(y_i-r(T_i))g_i\}\stackrel{!}{=}0
\end{align}
$$
Note that I have used the "$\stackrel{!}{=}0$" rather sloppily to indicate that, at $\theta=\theta^*$, the gradient of the problem must be zero, else we could improve the optimization further. Now we repeat the tools from above, i.e. invoke the notion that, $\mathrm{d}g$ must be zero when changing to another $y$. To this end, we need
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}g}{\mathrm{d}y}=-2\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\mathrm{d}r(T_1)}{\mathrm{d}\theta} &
\frac{\mathrm{d}r(T_2)}{\mathrm{d}\theta} &
\ldots &
\frac{\mathrm{d}r(T_n)}{\mathrm{d}\theta} 
\end{pmatrix}\equiv J
$$
which is of dimension $k \times n$ and of course
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}g}{\mathrm{d}\theta}=-2\sum_iy_iH_i-g_ig_i^T- r(T_i)H_i\equiv G
$$
which is of dimension $k \times k$
Finally, we have
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}\theta}{\mathrm{d}y}=-G^{-1}J
$$
which is of dimension $k \times n$ and to be calculated at $\theta=\theta^*$.
NB: Most optimizers will offer both Hessian and Jacobian of the model as a by-product, AFAIK.
IFT in standard bootstrapping
A common bootstrapping problem is to find a set of $K\leq N$ parameters $\theta$ (e.g. zero rate nodes in a interest rate curve) so that we can calibrate $N$ reference instruments to their respective quotes, stored in vector $Q$, dimension $N \times 1$.
Let $f$ be a $N\times 1$ vector of reference instruments that (conveniently) have to be priced at par (i.e. zero). Assume that $\theta^*$ has been calibrated such. Any update of $Q$ shall result in an update of $\theta$ such that, again, $f=0$. Then
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}y}=\frac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}\theta}\frac{\mathrm{d}\theta}{\mathrm{d}y}+\frac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}y}\stackrel{!}{=}0
$$
and again
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}\theta}{\mathrm{d}y}=-\left(\frac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}\theta}\right)^{-1}\frac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}y}
$$
If $K<N$, we have to come up with a pseudeo inverse, i.e.
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}\theta}{\mathrm{d}y}=-\left[\left(\frac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}\theta}\right)^T\frac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}\theta}\right]^{-1}\left(\frac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}\theta}\right)^T\frac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}y}
$$
A typical application, then, is to find sensitivites of some instrument $h$ in our portfolio with respect to market observed swap rates. Let $ \theta$ be parameters of the (zero-root) bootstrapped curve, commonly zero rates. Then:
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}h}{\mathrm{d}q}=\frac{\mathrm{d}h}{\mathrm{d}\theta}\frac{\mathrm{d}\theta}{\mathrm{d}r}=-\frac{\mathrm{d}h}{\mathrm{d}\theta}\left(\frac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}\theta}\right)^{-1}\frac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}y}
$$
where we use the "zero sensitivities" of our instrument and the (precomputed) sensitivities of the zero rates w.r.t. the quotes.

Great explanation, applies to calculating vega bucketed by expiry/moneyness of parametrized volatility surfaces/cubes as well.

The first method did the trick for me so thank you very very much!
Still I'm trying to understand why the second does not work in my case.
If I take my case still, with $y(T_i)$ the $i$th observation and $r(T_i)$ the NSS formula for maturity $T_i$. I construct my $f$ vector s.t $f=(y(T_1) - r_1(T_1),...,y(T_n) - r_n(T_n))$. Then I compute easily $\frac{df}{d\theta}$ which is of dim $n \times k$, and $\frac{df}{dy}=I_n$ is just the $n \times n$ identity matrix. And still the final result is wrong. I can't find where I diverged from the theory?

My math is a bit rusty there, so maybe the following goes in the wrong direction... If I remember correctly, the bootstrapping method ansatz only works if you truly bootstrap to all zeros, i.e. $f_i=0 \forall i$. This is only guaranteed under stronger model assumptions, i.e. for the Nelson Siegel Model, you must use the properties of the optimizer, but for "standard bootstrapping", you can use the Jacobians.
